# Matching PoS tags with specific text with `testacy.extract.pos_regex_matches(...)`

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm using `textacy`'s `pos_regex_matches` method to find certain chunks of text in sentences.

For instance, assuming I have the text: `Huey, Dewey, and Louie are triplet cartoon characters.`, I'd like to detect that `Huey, Dewey, and Louie` is an enumeration.

To do so, I use the following code (on `testacy 0.3.4`, the version available at the time of writing):

```
import textacy

sentence = 'Huey, Dewey, and Louie are triplet cartoon characters.'
pattern = r'<PROPN>+ (<PUNCT|CCONJ> <PUNCT|CCONJ>? <PROPN>+)*'
doc = textacy.Doc(sentence, lang='en')
lists = textacy.extract.pos_regex_matches(doc, pattern)
for list in lists:
    print(list.text)
```

which prints:

```
Huey, Dewey, and Louie
```

However, if I have something like the following:

```
sentence = 'Donald Duck - Disney'
```

then the `-` (dash) is recognised as `<PUNCT>` and the whole sentence is recognised as a list -- which it isn't.

Is there a way to specify that only `,` and `;` are valid `<PUNCT>` for lists?

I've looked for some reference about this regex language for matching PoS tags with no luck, can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

PS: I tried to replace `<PUNCT|CCONJ>` with `<[;,]|CCONJ>`, `<;,|CCONJ>`, `<[;,]|CCONJ>`, `<PUNCT[;,]|CCONJ>`, `<;|,|CCONJ>` and `<';'|','|CCONJ>` as suggested in the comments, but it didn't work...

Comment: Try replacing punct with [,;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is short, it is not possible: see [this official page](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy/pull/16).

However the merge request contains the code of the modified version described in the page, therefore one can recreate the functionality, despite it's less performing than using a `SpaCy`'s `Matcher` (see [code](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher.pyx) and [example](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/blob/master/examples/matcher_example.py) -- though I have no idea how to reimplement my problem using a `Matcher`).

If you want to go down this lane anyway, you have to change the line:

```
words.extend(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W', '', x), keyword_map[w]))
```

with the following:

```
words.extend(keyword_map[w])
```

otherwise every symbol (like `,` and `;` in my case) will be stripped off.